# Calling React setState from another class method doesn't update set

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to understand why I am unable to update state in the example below. Calling `removeFromOrder` directly works as expected but as soon as I am calling it from `deductOrderCount`, the state won't update.

Could someone please help me in understanding this?

I have reproduced the problem on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/pmesgari/pen/GRKYWKw?editors=1010)

```
class Order extends React.Component {
  renderOrder = (key) => {
    const item = this.props.items[key];
    const count = this.props.order[key];
    return (
      <li key={key}>
        {count} pieces of {item.name}
        <button onClick={() => this.props.deductOrderCount(key)}>&minus;</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.removeFromOrder(key)}>&times;</button>
      </li>
    )
  }
  render() {
    const orderIds = Object.keys(this.props.order);
    return (
      <div>
        {orderIds.map(this.renderOrder)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: { item1: { name: 'chocolate', price: 100}, item2: { name: 'bread', price: 50}},
    order: { item1: 3, item2: 2 }
  };

  removeFromOrder = key => {
    console.log('removing from order ' + key);
    // 1. take a copy of state
    const order = { ...this.state.order };
    // 2. remove item from order
    delete order[key];
    console.log(order)
    // 3. call setState to update our state object
    this.setState({ order });
  };

  deductOrderCount = (key) => {
    // 1. take a copy of state
    const order = { ...this.state.order };
    // 2. deduct 1 from the count and when it hits 0 remove from the order
    order[key] = (order[key] > 1) ? (order[key] - 1) : 0;
    if (order[key] === 0) this.removeFromOrder(key) //delete order[key]
    // 3. call setState to update our state object
    this.setState({ order })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Order
          order={this.state.order}
          items={this.state.items} 
          removeFromOrder={this.removeFromOrder}  
          deductOrderCount={this.deductOrderCount}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("main"));
```

Comment: On `order[key] === 0` you updating the state twice, 
once from `removeFromOrder` and then you override it with `this.setState({ order })`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the else then you call the `deductOrderCount`, you are updating two times the **order in the state**
Try something like this

```
deductOrderCount = (key) => {
    // 1. take a copy of state
    const order = { ...this.state.order };
    // 2. deduct 1 from the count and when it hits 0 remove from the order
    order[key] = (order[key] > 1) ? (order[key] - 1) : 0;
    if (order[key] === 0) this.removeFromOrder(key) //delete order[key]
    else this.setState({ order }) // 3. call setState to update our state object

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to call removeFromOrder() function inside the deductOrderCount() function as it will update the state twice as updating twice will give different state

Answer (score 0):

It's because you should return this.removeFromOrder() function to not setState again after calling it.

So insted of:
`if (order[key] === 0) this.removeFromOrder(key) //delete order[key]`

go with:
`if (order[key] === 0) return this.removeFromOrder(key) //delete order[key]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, indeed I was updating the state twice. I got to see it by just adding a `setTimeout(() => {this.setState({ order })}, 3000)` in `deductOrderCount`. And then I saw the item was removed from the state once `removeFromOrder` was invoked, and then appeared again.

```
class Order extends React.Component {
  renderOrder = (key) => {
    const item = this.props.items[key];
    const count = this.props.order[key];
    return (
      <li key={key}>
        {count} pieces of {item.name}
        <button onClick={() => this.props.deductOrderCount(key)}>&minus;</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.removeFromOrder(key)}>&times;</button>
      </li>
    )
  }
  render() {
    const orderIds = Object.keys(this.props.order);
    return (
      <div>
        {orderIds.map(this.renderOrder)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: { item1: { name: 'chocolate', price: 100}, item2: { name: 'bread', price: 50}},
    order: { item1: 3, item2: 2 }
  };

  removeFromOrder = key => {
    // 1. take a copy of state
    const order = { ...this.state.order };
    // 2. remove item from order
    delete order[key];
    // 3. call setState to update our state object
    this.setState({ order });
  };

  deductOrderCount = (key) => {
    // 1. take a copy of state
    const order = { ...this.state.order };
    // 2. deduct 1 from the count and when it hits 0 remove from the order
    order[key] = (order[key] > 1) ? (order[key] - 1) : 0;
    if (order[key] === 0) this.removeFromOrder(key); //delete order[key]
    // 3. call setState to update our state object
    setTimeout(() => {this.setState({ order })}, 3000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Order
          order={this.state.order}
          items={this.state.items} 
          removeFromOrder={this.removeFromOrder}  
          deductOrderCount={this.deductOrderCount}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("main"));
```